# yaml file create a container cluster in google cloud platform

Tags: yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, google-deployment-manager

I am trying create a cluster with the help of deployment manager script. I found some python scripts to do that in GitHub. But I am looking for YAML file. PLease share any reference.